# How to: Monitor progress of data in a pipe?

Tags: windows, multithreading, winapi, visual-c++, pipe

Have a 1MB pipe:

```
if (0 == CreatePipe(&hRead,&hWrite,0,1024*1024))
{
printf("CreatePipe failed\n");
return success;
}
```

Sending 4000 bytes at a time (bytesReq = 4000)

```
while ((bytesReq = (FileSize - offset)) != 0)
{


//Send data to Decoder.cpp thread, converting to human readable CSV
        if ( (0 == WriteFile(hWrite,
                               readBuff,
                               bytesReq,
                               &bytesWritten,
                               0) ) || 
                               (bytesWritten != bytesReq) )
        {
             printf("WriteFile failed error = %d\n",GetLastError());
             break;
        } 

// Would like to update a status box with the amount of data in the pipe.
I would like to know if and how often it is getting full....



}
```

**4 bytes** at a time being read in an other thread, on other end of pipe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before reading the 4 bytes you can read the available bytes by using [PeekNamedPipe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365779%28VS.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Not sure this tells me the current capacity of the pipe:                   

"if the buffer size is zero, the buffer is allocated as needed"